# Jenkins Workflow Build Information

Tags: groovy, jenkins, jenkins-workflow

How do you access current, and related, build information from within a Jenkins workflow groovy script?

I can see things like currentBuild.result and currentBuild.previousBuild being documented, but I can't see how I can access, for example:

- The URL of the current build job.
- The URL of build jobs that this workflow triggered.
- The console output of a particular failed build job, etc.

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Where did you find documentation about currentBuild.previousBuild? I can't find this documentation

Comment: @GabrielOliveira: It is under http://<your-jenkins-server>/pipeline-syntax/globals

Comment: thanks @FuzzY! I checked this page earlier but I think it was updated in some version.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`currentBuild.rawBuild` will give you the non cached `hudson.model.Run` object, see [hudson.model.Run](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Run.html)

from there, to access i.e. the build log:

```
def buildLog = currentBuild.rawBuild.log
```

`currentBuild.rawBuild` is also of type [hudson.model.AbstractBuild](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/AbstractBuild.html) which can give you other details like `changeset`, `actions`

Comment: note you'll have to run it outside of groovy sandbox to access rawBuild

Comment: @Vano That's a good point to raise and I'll add that you can accomplish this by annotating the method with `@NonCPS`.