# Jenkins pipeline MissingMethodException: No signature of method:

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I wrote a function to insert inject a variable through the EnvInj-plugin. Following script I used:

```
import hudson.model.*
import static hudson.model.Cause.RemoteCause

@com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
def call(currentBuild) {
    def ipaddress=""
    for (CauseAction action : currentBuild.getActions(CauseAction.class)) {

        for (Cause cause : action.getCauses()) {
            if(cause instanceof RemoteCause){
                ipaddress=cause.addr
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return ["ip":ipaddress]
}
```

When I put it the the folder $JENKINS_HOME/workflow-libs/vars as a global function, i get the following error:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper.getActions() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Class) values: [class hudson.model.CauseAction]
```

I am completly new in groovy, so I don't know why it is not working. With the EnvInj-plugin it was fine. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably need the `rawbuild` property of the `currentBuild`.

The following script should do it for you.

```
//$JENKINS_HOME/workflow-libs/vars/getIpAddr.groovy
@com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
def call() {
    def addr = currentBuild.rawBuild.getActions(CauseAction.class)
        .collect { actions ->
            actions.causes.find { cause -> 
                cause instanceof hudson.model.Cause.RemoteCause 
            }
        }
    ?.first()?.addr
    [ ip: addr ]
}
```

if you use it like:

```
def addressInfo = getIpAddr()
def ip = addressInfo.ip
```

Note that it will be `null` if there are no `RemoteCause` actions

You might want to return only the `addr` instead of the hashmap `[ ip: addr ]`, like so

```
//$JENKINS_HOME/workflow-libs/vars/getIpAddr.groovy
@com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.NonCPS
def call() {
    currentBuild.rawBuild.getActions(CauseAction.class)
        .collect { actions ->
            actions.causes.find { cause -> 
                cause instanceof hudson.model.Cause.RemoteCause 
            }
        }
    ?.first()?.addr
}
```

and then

```
def addressInfo = [ ip: getIpAdder() ]
```

Alos note that, depending on the security of your Jenkins, you might need to allow the running of extension methods in sandboxed scripts. You will notice a `RejectedSandboxException`

You can solve this by approving this through `Manage Jenkins` -> `In-process Script Approval`

Hope it works